# correct minor mistakes

Tags: python

to make links (use https whenever possible)
https://example.com
`enter code here`[example](https://example.com)
`enter code here`[example](https://example.com)

formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with this `evenNumbers` method:

```
   public MyList evenNumbers(MyList original) {

        MyList evenList = new MyList();
        Node prev = null;

        Node next = original.myBeginning;

        while (next != null) {
            if (next.info % 2 == 0) {
                Node newEvenNode = new Node(next.info);
                if (prev == null) {
                    evenList.myBeginning = newEvenNode;
                } else {
                    prev.pointer = newEvenNode;
                }
                evenList.size++;
                prev = newEvenNode;
            }
            next = next.pointer;
        }

        return evenList;
    }
```

I also looked at your code. One problem is that you never assign a node to the beginning of the new list.  A second problem is that you try to get the next Node with `next.pointer`, but this value can only be `null` as the next Node does not even exist.

Also, I solved your problem with a `while` loop, but using the `for` loop is also fine.